# How to use F# types from C# wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, f#

In F# I have code with structure like this:

```ml
module MyNS.MyModule

type SomeType =
    member x.value = "some value"
```

Assemble with it code named `MyNs`. I referenced to it from C# WPF application and do the same in XAML:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="WpfTest"
             xmlns:data="clr-namespace:MyNS;assembly=MyNs">
```

then I trying to used `SomeType` in `DataTemplate`:

```xml
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type data:MyModule.SomeType}">
```

But have an error about missing type.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287437/c-sharp-wpf-project-with-reference-to-f-viewmodel

Comment: Actually, the other question is yours. What is the difference between them?

Comment: What exactly is the error you're getting?

Comment: My other question does not specify that I want use F# types from module. There peoples have found other error, not about I asked here. This question about using types from F# modules represented in C# by public classes as I know.

Comment: @svick, Error 1 The type reference cannot find a public type named 'ViewModel.TestResultModel'. Line 825 Position 93. D:\dev\ATPC\ATCheckerView\TestsPropagate.xaml 825 93 ATCheckerView

Comment: The error is about a type that doesn't seem to be mentioned anywhere in the code you posted, so I think the error is somewhere else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it should look like below, with `MyModule+SomeType` instead of  `MyModule.SomeType` for a nested class.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfTest"
             xmlns:data="clr-namespace:MyNS;assembly=MyNs">

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type data:MyModule+SomeType}">
```

Found it [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12807195/1136211).

Comment: Error 2 Undefined CLR namespace. The 'clr-namespace' URI refers to a namespace 'ATChecker.ViewModel' that is not included in the assembly. D:\dev\ATPC\ATCheckerView\TestsPropagate.xaml 4 25 ATCheckerView

Comment: because MyModule isn't namespace, it like C# public class